How to prevent failure in Expresso Unit Test with application restarting (Runtime exit + start activity)?
I have an Android application that restarts after a certain process finishes via:
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName() );
activity.startActivity(Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(launchIntent.getComponent()));
Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);

My expresso unit test fails when the above code is called. Is there a way to allow the above code to run without the expresso failure?
